# Can I setText to an EditText in another Intent?

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-edittext, settext

I want to SetText to an EditText in another intent..

I have an EditText in First Intent and I want to SetText in Second Intent , Can i do that? How?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can! Get the text from the EditText like this.

```
String value = editText.getText().toString();
```

Then send this value to the second activity like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("any", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can now get this value from the next activity like this.

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
String Value = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("any");
```

Comment: sorry i don't need that , i need setText to an EditText in second Activity, not getText

Comment: but i try this and its not work for me... because my EditText in first Intent i want to set a text from another aactivity

Comment: I don't think you can do that